# PostgreSQL connection creation taking time

Tags: postgresql

We are using postgreSQL-8.2 with CentOS6 and Java 1.5. When we create a connection and query the system with a simple query everything works fine. However when we keep increasing the threads that call postgreSQL from java at about 50 threads the connection creation takes over 2 seconds. This is consistently happening.

The connection count is 150 connection, server has 8GB of memory and 4 vCPU's. We do not see any disk IO issues, memory issues or CPU issues when checking top command.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: 0) pg-8.2 is EOL. 1) what is your work_mem setting ? 2) do you have autovacuum running ?

Comment: work_mem - 64M , no autovacuum . we run a scheduled vacuum at certain times of the day.